# Grouping rows into windows based on values in a column in R

Tags: r

I would like to group rows into windows based on coordinates in one of the columns.

e.g., from the following data frame:

```
coordinate  value
2   123
5   234
13  345
16  456
18  567
25  678
```

I need to group rows into windows based on 'coordinate', i.e. if window 1 = 1:10, window 2 = 11:20 etc., then the desired output would be:

```
coordinate  value   window
2   123 1
5   234 1
13  345 2
16  456 2
18  567 2
25  678 3
```

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

In order to group rows into windows based on the 'coordinate' column in R, you can use the cut() function to create a new 'window' column based on the specified window boundariesn e.g  Windows of 10. Here's an example:

```
# Your data
df <- data.frame(coordinate = c(2, 5, 13, 16, 18, 25),
                 value = c(123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678))

# Define window boundaries
window_boundaries <- seq(1, max(df$coordinate)+10, by = 10)

# Create 'window' column
df$window <- cut(df$coordinate, breaks = window_boundaries, labels = FALSE)

# Print the resulting data frame
print(df)
```

Output:
coordinate value window

1          2   123      1

2          5   234      1

3         13   345      2

4         16   456      2

5         18   567      2

6         25   678      3

Comment: had to change df.window and df.coordinate to df$window and df$coordinate, but it worked, thanks.